# Given an array of ints, what is the most efficient way to split the array down the middle into two arrays of shorts?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm

It struck me there must be a clever way to do this.  This isn't for homework, or work or anything.  I was just noodling around with a file format that has data interleaved.

So, in generic C/C++, (or whatever) given some array

```
int x[] = ...
```

is there a clever way of splitting it into two short arrays

```
short sa1[], sa2[]
```

such that the int array is split down the middle

```
x[i] = 1111111111111111 1111111111111111
             sa1[i]         sa2[i]
```

Edit: Sorry if this is not phrased well. For each i-th element of the int array, the left-most 16 bits become the i-th element of one array, and the right-most 16bits become the i-th element of a 2nd array.

so given

```
x[i] = 0001111111111111 1111111100011111
```

then

```
sa1[i] = 0001111111111111
sa2[i] = 1111111100011111
```

I'm looking for non-obvious answers that do not loop over each element and shift and mask each element.  That's easy :)

Comment: In generic C/C++? Or on some specific platform?

Comment: @ David Schwartz  - generic C/C++.  Doesn't matter.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid copying?  Making the short arrays occupy the same memory as the int array?

Comment: The obvious answer (linear iteration) is cache friendly and touches each element only once. It can be tuned or unrolled but there isn't much room for improvement without going parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to do this:

Assumptions:

1. `short` is 16 bits.
2. `int` is 32 bits.

Method 1: (A simple loop)

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    int tmp = x[i];
    sa1[i] = (tmp      ) & 0xffff;
    sa2[i] = (tmp >> 16) & 0xffff;
}
```

Method 2: SSE2

```
for (int i = 0; i < size / 8; i++){
    __m128i a0 = ((__m128i*)x)[2*i + 0];
    __m128i a1 = ((__m128i*)x)[2*i + 1];

    a0 = _mm_shufflelo_epi16(a0,216);
    a1 = _mm_shufflelo_epi16(a1,216);
    a0 = _mm_shufflehi_epi16(a0,216);
    a1 = _mm_shufflehi_epi16(a1,216);
    a0 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(a0,216);
    a1 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(a1,216);

    ((__m128i*)sa1)[i] = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(a0,a1);
    ((__m128i*)sa2)[i] = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(a0,a1);
}
```

This last example is very fast if the loop is further unrolled. I won't be surprised if this can beat all byte-manipulation libraries.

However, it has the following restrictions:

1. The data must be aligned to 16 bytes.
2. The number of iterations must be divisible by 8.
3. It requires SSE2.

The first two of these can be solved by cleanup code. It's messy, but if you really desire performance, it may be worth it.

EDIT:

Yes this violates strict-aliasing, but it's nearly impossible to use SSE intrinsics without doing so.

Answer (score 3):

**If** `int` is exactly two `short`s on your platform, you can just `reinterpret_cast` the `int` array into `short` array, then take even/odd elements.

Note however, that size of `int` versus `short` is not guaranteed (other than `short` cannot be larger than `int`). For example `int` may be equal to `short` or it may be more than 2 `short`s. Even the *absolute* size of `int` is not guaranteed (typical sizes are 4 and 8 bytes).

For truly portable solution, you'll probably be better off mapping the exact format of the file you are trying to interpret into [bit fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: This is a violation of the strict aliasing rules, so doing this invokes undefined behavior. Nasal demons aside, this might be an issue depending on how it is used.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose Could you please clarify? Say, if `int` is 4 bytes and `short` 2, would that "violate strict aliasing rules"?

Comment: In brief, an object can't he accessed via a pointer to anything except the actual type. There's a few exceptions, like to `char*` and to a base class, but this isn't one of them. It will likely work, but being undefined behavior the compiler can still churn out unexpected results, especially when optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know the length of x, but you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int xlen = 6;

    short * a = &x[0];
    short * b = &x[xlen/2];

    printf("%d\n%d\n", a[0], b[0]);
}
```

`a` points to the beginning of the original `int` array, and allows you to index in `short` increments. Same deal with `b`, except it starts from the middle of the original `int` array.

I would call this clever, but you will get a warning from gcc about incompatible pointer types. This is the kind of thing I might do in an embedded environment, but I would make sure it doesn't cause any security issues in a less controlled environment.

Comment: The warning is because you omitted a cast. In C++ you should use `reinterpret_cast`. Also this isn't what the question is asking.

Comment: The original question seems unclear. "interleaved" versus "a clever way of splitting it into two short arrays such that the int array is split down the middle". I feel like I answered the latter, but you're right, my solution has nothing to do with interleaved data.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't phrase my question well, but this is not what I meant.  What I meant was the left-most 16 bits of each element become an element of one array, and the right-most 16bits become an element of a 2nd array.  See Mysticial's answer.